# Datetime conversion failure due to able to delete the leading zero

Tags: python, datetime, time

I am new to python and would like to inquire a question.
I have the following time series data in csv file and would like to delete the leading zero in order to let myself to make the time as an integer but I could not find any way to do so (by python / excel methods). Please help if possible.

```
Time
09:15:00.0
09:16:00.0
09:17:00.0
09:18:00.0
.......
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make the time as an integer"? In what situation would the leading zero be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each of these rows is a string called `time_row`, you could use slicing like so `time_row[1:]`. This would skip the first character and include everything to the end.